# How To Properly Compress UIImages At Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiimage

I need to load 4 images for simultaneous editing. When I load them from the users library, the memory exceeds 500mb and crashes.

Here is a log from a raw allocations dump before I did any compression attempts:

Code:

```
var pickedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Instrument:
[image]

I have read several posts on compressing UIImages. I have tried reducing the UIImage:

New Code:

```
var pickedImage = UIImage(data: imageData, scale:0.1)
```

Instrument:
[image]

Reducing the scale of the UIImage had NO EFFECT?! Very odd.

So now I tried creating a JPEG compression based on the full UIImage

New code:

```
var pickedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
var compressedData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,0)
var compressedImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: compressedData)!//this is now used to display
```

Instrument:

[image]

Now, I suspect because I am converting the image its still being loaded. And since this is all occuring inside a callback from PHImageManager, I need a way to create a compressed UIImage from the NSData, but the setting the scale to 0.1 did NOTHING.

So any suggestions as to how I can compress this UIImage right from the NSData would be life saving!!!

Thanks

Comment: have you try using [link](https://github.com/AliSoftware/UIImage-Resize) ?

Comment: Yea that way is old school but thank you (its overkill). I did figure out another solution which I can post tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up hard coding a size reduction before processing the image. Here is the code:

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize:CGSizeMake(CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth), CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight)), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options)
{
  result, info in
  var minRatio:CGFloat = 1
  //Reduce file size so take 1/2 UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2 || CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight) > UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2)
  {
    minRatio = min((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2)/(CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth)), ((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2)/CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight)))
  }

  var size:CGSize = CGSizeMake((CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth)*minRatio),(CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight)*minRatio))
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
  result.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
  var final = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  var image = iImage(uiimage: final)
}
```

Comment: i have the same problem in objective-C. This is my question link==>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034703/how-to-handle-multiple-images-with-large-size . Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having crashes and seeing such high memory usage is that you are missing the call to `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();` -- so you are leaking memory like crazy.

For every call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, make sure you have a call to `UIGraphicsEndImageContext (after UIGraphicsGetImage*)`.

Also, you should wrap in `@autorelease` (I'm presuming you're using ARC), otherwise you'll still have out-of-memory crashes if you are rapidly processing images.

Do it like this:

```
@autorelease {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(...);
  ..
  something = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```